# Differential equation $\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}+\frac{dy}{\sqrt{1-y^4}}=0$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

> Prove that the general integral of the equation $\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}+\frac{dy}{\sqrt{1-y^4}}=0$ can be represented in the form $y\sqrt{1-x^4}+x\sqrt{1-y^4}=C\left ( 1+x^2y^2 \right )$

I tried to take the integral $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}$, but it turns out to be an elliptic function and it is not yet clear how to express the required equality from it. Can you show how you can prove it?

Comment: That's indeed an elliptic integral (of the first kind, I believe). The equation is exact, but the resulting integral is nothing nice.

Comment: Could you please include some personal work please?

Comment: This is connected to the lemnicate curve : see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/189806/305862).